# Query a dynamic deduplicated table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery to give my colleagues access to aggregated data in our system.

I have a `raw_orders` table where I store orders data. The thing is that the lines in this table are subject to change across time. When a change occurs, I add a new line in this table. So my table looks like this:

```
+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | total |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ABC | 15.76 | 2020-01-01 12:56:32 | 2020-01-02 14:58:43 |
| ABC | 12.43 | 2020-01-01 12:56:32 | 2020-01-01 12:56:32 |
| DEF | 19.03 | 2020-01-01 12:56:32 | 2020-01-02 14:58:43 |
| DEF | 12.03 | 2020-01-01 12:56:32 | 2020-01-01 12:56:32 |
+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

To allow my collaborators to query on a deduplicated table easily, I created a view of deduplicated lines using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW xxx.orders as
select ro.*
from (
  select ro.id, max(ro.updated_at) max_updated_at
  from xxx.raw_orders ro
  group by ro.id
) tmp inner join xxx.raw_orders ro2 on ro2.id = tmp.id && ro2.updated_at = tmp.max_updated_at
order by f.created_at desc
```

This works great, but I feel that I am spending too much budget on simple requests like:

```
SELECT * FROM rubee.orders WHERE created_at > '2020-11-01 00:00:00';
```

If I understand well, because of the view step, big query must use a lot of storage to deduplicate lines before responding a single result.

**Am I doing something wrong here? How do you give access to deduplicated data without spending too much storage? Would you have a better strategy for what I try to do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you will use a materialized view for the purpose, but right now BigQuery has [limited support on materialized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views#supported_mvs). You cannot create a mview to replace the view you were using.

It is possible to create a materialized view for the inner query, which **may** make the whole query less expensive but please read on.

- Cost. There is no simple answer whether you are "spending too much budget" on the query.

  - If you're on pay-per-query plan and charged by "processed bytes", then although the query is more expensive for BigQuery to process, you're charged no more than scanning the whole table once (although technically the table was scanned more than once). In another word, deduplication is free. However, if your query pattern allows to to cluster/partition your table somehow to avoid scanning the whole table, then this "self-join" view does prevent you from saving the budget.
  - If you have reservation on slots, then you will benefit from making the query faster.
- Suggestions. Give the situation is different case by case, the general suggestions are:

  - If it is possible, separating the data into "archived" and "active" so that "archived" data stay deduplicated (and partitioned/clustered to allow efficient search), and you only need a view to dedup "active" data.
  - Create a materialized view (on the inner "GROUP BY" query) may speed up the query a bit but not necessarily make it "cheaper", you may be charged the size of the base table + mview.